# What is the proper way to cache a http header tag?

Tags: meta-tags

I find examples of adding a header meta tag, such as using an event subscriber or using hook_page_attachments.

The problem I have is that both of these methods add the tag only in the case of an authenticated user request. The anonymous cache work is done way before either of these methods fire, and even if I could force my change to a higher priority, I don't know that I would want that to happen on every anonymous page request.

In detail, when I subscribe to the response event, and set the header tag, it appears on the rendered page for an authenticated user. However, that tag is apparently not added to cache, because any subsequent anonymous requests do not include that tag. I'm assuming, then, that I need to trigger some mechanism to have the tag added to cache and not simply injected in the header during rendering.

What I want to do is persist a header meta tag in cache so that is included in anonymous requests. The tag value is based on a node field that only needs to be cached when it changes, so the node save event would be the ideal time.

What is the proper way of getting a custom header meta tag into the cache for a specific node?

Here is the code of my subscription, which fires for authenticated traffic, but is not persisted in cache:

```
namespace Drupal\my_http_injector\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;class MyHttpInjector implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    /**
     * Trigger pulled
     */
    public function onRespond(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
        $response = $event->getResponse();
        // Get the response attachments

        if (is_object($response)) {
            if (method_exists($response, 'getAttachments')) {
                $attachments = $response->getAttachments();
                if (is_array($attachments) &&
                    isset($attachments['drupalSettings']) &&
                    isset($attachments['drupalSettings']['path']) &&
                    isset($attachments['drupalSettings']['path']['currentPath'])) {
                    // Get the requested path
                    $path = '/' . $attachments['drupalSettings']['path']['currentPath'];
                    $params = Url::fromUri("internal:" . $path)->getRouteParameters();
                    $entity_type = key($params);
                    if ($entity_type == 'node') {
                        $node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->load($params[$entity_type]);
                        if (is_object($node)) {
                            $date = gmdate(DATE_RFC1123, $node->getChangedTime());
                            $response->headers->set('Last-Modified', $date);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        $events[KernelEvents::RESPONSE][] = ['onRespond'];
        return $events;
    }
```

Comment: This is how caching works, the cache delivers pages before any code to build the page (not only the custom code for the header tags) is run  and the cached page include the header tags you've set before. So this is the proper way. There seems to be an issue with your specific implementation, please provide more details.

Comment: I've added more detail.

Comment: The page cache stores the whole responses and this includes anything you've added in custom code. But I can't tell what is wrong in your case, can be a missing cache tag (although if you display a node the cache tag should already be there) or the response subscriber is not triggered for anonymous traffic, even after a cache clear.

Comment: I've added the code from my subscriber.

Comment: You can get the node directly from `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')`. Anonymous responses have `drupalSettings` only if you attach the corresponding js libraries.

Comment: So getting the node is only necessary in my case to determine the header tag value. Given that I’m trying either to cache the tag or append it even on an anonymous request, which does having drupalSettings present accomplish?

Comment: There is no either and it's the other way. First you append the header to the response and then the response is cached including the header. Since you need to clear the cache anyway after introducing a new response subscriber, all responses added to the empty cache will include the header. If the code works for anonymous traffic, which I can't debug from here.

Comment: That would seem to be what I’ve done. The tag is added to the response in the subscriber, and then appears in the response on the authenticated request. Neither the subscriber fires nor subsequent anonymous requests contain the tag any longer.

Comment: As said before I can't debug your code, so I've posted a simpler version of the event subscriber which should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the header in an event subscriber

```
  public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    $node = $this->routeMatch->getParameter('node');
    // if you don't have injected $this->routeMatch use \Drupal::routeMatch()
    if ($node && $node instanceof NodeInterface) {
      $date = gmdate(DATE_RFC1123, $node->getChangedTime());
      $response->headers->set('Last-Modified', $date);
    }
  }
```

and it will get cached for authenticated and anonymous requests.

If you use additional dependencies add them to the response as well:

```
  if ($response instanceof CacheableResponseInterface) {
    $response->addCacheableDependency($entity);
  }
```

This is not necessary in this case because the rendering of the node has already added the cache data.

Comment: Removed preceding comment. It does work with the onResponse and your use of routeMatch!  Thank you!