# How to set headers in REST API endpoints for GET method?

Tags: 8

I am writing Rest api end point for GET method and testing the same in postman client. By default there is no Header for encoding technique called utf-8. I want to send it in Response headers manually. So I tried like below:

```
$response = new ResourceResponse($newsfeed, 200);
$response->headers->set('charset', 'utf-8');
```

After this I got this in postman Headers like :`Charset: utf-8`.

I am just wondering is this right way to set or is there any alternative efficient way to handle it? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Yes, this is the right way. If you want to set a header for all responses of a specific type then use an event subscriber, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/262716/47547

Comment: Thank you @4k4, I am just wondering why its not added by default to Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 like this. Am i missing something while sending response?